# Expression for Lookup activity result when stored procedure returns scalar value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a Lookup activity that returns an scalar result and I want to use that result to build a dinamic query using a concat expression. However, I'm receiving an error complaining that my SQL query is not well formated. This is how I'm building the query:

```
@concat('SELECT v.CscadaEventId as EventId, 
v.EndDate as EndDateUtc 
FROM v_cscadaevents v 
INNER JOIN cscadaevents e
ON e.cscadaeventId = v.CscadaEventId 
WHERE v.CscadaEventId IN(', activity('LookupUnfinishedAlarms').output.firstRow, ') AND e.EndDate IS NOT NULL;')
```

I expect that to return a query like this:

```
SELECT v.CscadaEventId as EventId, 
v.EndDate as EndDateUtc 
FROM v_cscadaevents v 
INNER JOIN cscadaevents e
ON e.cscadaeventId = v.CscadaEventId WHERE v.CscadaEventId IN(2329390,2340616,2342078,2345857,2361240,2362088,2362574,2377062,2378594,2379357) AND e.EndDate IS NOT NULL;
```

I had see some examples where the lookup return multiple columns, and the right expression is `activity('LookupUnfinishedAlarms').output.firstRow.myColumnName` but what about when the lookup activity return an scalar value, as in  my case?

This is the full error so far:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   '\"output\":\"2329390,2340616,2342078,2345857,2361240,2362088,2362574,2377062,237859'
>   at line
>   6,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
>   [42000] [Microsoft][MariaDB] You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near
>   '\"output\":\"2329390,2340616,2342078,2345857,2361240,2362088,2362574,2377062,237859'
>   at line 6,Source=MariaDBODBC_sb64.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for the records, I found the solution. The expression must be:

```
@concat('SELECT v.CscadaEventId as EventId, 
v.EndDate as EndDateUtc 
FROM v_cscadaevents v 
INNER JOIN cscadaevents e
ON e.cscadaeventId = v.CscadaEventId 
WHERE v.CscadaEventId IN(', activity('LookupUnfinishedAlarms').output.firstRow.output, ') AND e.EndDate IS NOT NULL;')
```

So, the default column becomes `output`